# 15 MB SQLite database file from Chrome history shown blank

Tags: google-chrome, database, history, file-corruption, sqlite

I accidentally removed the profile from my Chrome on Windows and everything disappeared.

Except I was able to recover 15 MB history file from my hard drive it said the file was not corrupted.

But when I open It with any SQLite database reader, it is shown empty.

I don't know anything about this stuff.

Can someone help me, or does someone know how to access this file ?

It is 14 MB big, cant be empty.

Comment: is there absolutely no one?

Comment: is someone able to use this tool? I believe this could be it: http://pldaniels.com/undark/